# Error in .jcall()

Tags: r

estoy utilizando la siguiente función para guardar una hoja de excel proveniente de R en un libro de excel existente reemplazando esta misma hoja, es decir tengo un libro de excel con varias hojas una de ella con el nombre Depositos y quiero exportar el df de R en excel guardándolo en el mismo libre y reemplazando la hoja Depositos

```
write.xlsx2(uno, file = "//152.55.212.58/compartida/Insumo/Prueba.xlsx", sheetName = "Depositos", append = TRUE, row.names = False)
```

Sin emabargo me registra el siguiente error:

> Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;",
> "createSheet",  :    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook
> already contains a sheet of this name

el error aparece con cualquier tamaño de archivo, sea de gran volumen o pequeño, alguno ha tenido una solución??

Comment: No se permite hacer un append sobre una hoja que ya existe, dale otro nombre a `sheetName` o no hagas `append = TRUE`

Comment: Buenas tardes Patricio, en este caso al realizarlo como sugieres me registra lo siguiente 

Error in .jcall=RJavaTOOLS", "Ljava/lang/object;", "invokemethod", cl,:
java.lang.outofmemoryerror: Hava heap space

Answer (score 0):

En la versión inglesa de stack**overflow** hay una solución a tu pregunta. El enlace a la respuesta original es [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053185/using-write-xlsx-to-replace-an-existing-sheet-with-r-package-xlsx)

En principio no puedes sustituir la hoja directamente. Lo que si que puede hacer es cargar el libro entero, modificar la hoja que quieras y volver a guardar el libro entero.

Los pasos ha seguir serian:

1. Cargar el libro

   `wb <- loadWorkbook('directorio/del/archivo.xlsx')`
2. Obtener las hojas del libro

   `hojas <- getSheets(wb)`
3. Eliminar la hoja de interés

   `removeSheet(wb, sheetName = 'nombreHoja')`
4. Crear una nueva hoja

   `hojaNueva <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = 'nombreHoja')`
5. Añadir tus datos a la hoja

   `addDataFrame(tusDatos, hojaNueva, <opciones>)`
6. Guardar el libro con los nuevos datos

   `saveWorkbook(wb, 'archivo.xlsx')`

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda sin embargo al querer cargar el libro me aparece un error in sprintf()

Comment: Hola Ivan, ¿podrías incluir el código que has ejecutado i el error completo?. Hago una modificación de la respuesta porque faltan una comillas en `achivo.xlsx`.